# why is my multiple dropdowns menus not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make two dropdown menus using the code below

The first button with myFunction() work fine but the 2nd my() only work when I click on the button I want to make it response whenever click at any place at the window

I try to make handle with `eventlistener` to make the `window.onclick` work with the two button

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function my() {
  document.getElementById("myaccountDropdown").classList.toggle("showed");
}
// Function to handle clicks on the window
function handleClick(event) {
  // Check if the click target is NOT the "dropbtn" element
  if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
    // Get references to all the dropdown-content elements
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    // Loop through the dropdown-content elements
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      // Check if the current dropdown-content element has the "show" class
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
        // If it does, remove the "show" class to close the dropdown
        openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
      }
    }
  }

  // Check if the click target is the "clicked" element
  if (event.target.matches(".clicked")) {
    // Get references to all the dropdown-accountsettings elements
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-accountsetting");
    // Loop through the dropdown-accountsettings elements
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      // Check if the current dropdown-accountsettings element has the "showed" class
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains("showed")) {
        // If it does, remove the "showed" class to close the dropdown
        openDropdown.classList.remove("showed");
      }
    }
  }
}

// Add the event listener to the window
window.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #242222;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn .fa {
  position: relative;
  right: -3px;
}


/*  account logo setting */

.clicked {
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clicked:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.account-logo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-accountsetting {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #242222;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-accountsetting a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-accountsetting a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.showed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <p onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
    Categories
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down icon" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
  </p>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</li>

<div class="account-logo">
  <p onclick="my()" class="dropbtn">
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </p>
  <div id="myaccountDropdown" class="dropdown-accountsetting">
    <a href="#">Linked 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it  [mcve]